# Dynamically creating DIVs and adding DIVs inside of the new DIVs with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to Create pages with DIVs dynamically for my phonegap app from the database with the query below. 
To keep it simple for this the database will have only 2 columns, "ID" and "Data":

```
function querySuccessOrders(tx, results) {
console.log("Successful QUERY of the Table");
var len = results.rows.length;

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){ 
    $('#body').append('<div data-role="page" id="coi'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'" data-theme="b"></div>');
}

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
    $('#coi'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" id="coi_header'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'"></div>');
}

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
    $('#coi'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="infoGuts'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'"></div>');
}

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
    $('#coi'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer-docs" data-theme="b" id="coi_footer'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'"></div>');
}

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
    $('#coi_header'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<h1>ID #'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'</h1>');
    $('#coi_header'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<a href="#page" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" id="intro" class="ui-btn-right"></a>');  
}

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
    $('#coi_header'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<div data-role="navbar" data-theme="b" id="coi_navbar'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'"></div>');
}

  for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
    $('#coi_header'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<div data-role="navbar" data-theme="b" id="coi_navbar'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'"></div>');
}

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
    $('#coi_navbar'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<ul>');
    $('#coi_navbar'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<li><a href="#COI'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'">COI</a></li>');
    $('#coi_navbar'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<li><a href="#COP'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'">COP</a></li>');
    $('#coi_navbar'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<li><a href="#COQ'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'">COQ</a></li>');
    $('#coi_navbar'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('</ul>');
}

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){  
    $('#coi_footer'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('<p>footer</p>');     
}

for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    $('#info'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('ID:'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'<br />');
    $('#info'+results.rows.item(i).ID+'').append('Data:'+results.rows.item(i).Data+'<br />');
}

}
```

Essentially I am trying to get the body to look like this dynamically:

```
    <body id="body">

<div data-role="page" id="coi1" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" id="coi_header1">
        <h1>ID #1</h1>
        <a href="#page" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" id="intro" class="ui-btn-right"></a>
            <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="b" id="coi_navbar1">

                         <ul>
                           <li><a href="#COI1">COI</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#COP1">COP</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#COQ1">COQ</a></li>
                         </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="infoGuts1">
           ID:1<br />
           Data: asd <br />
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer-docs" data-theme="b" id="coi_footer1">
     <p>footer</p>  
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="coi2" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" id="coi_header2">
        <h1>ID #2</h1>
        <a href="#page" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" id="intro" class="ui-btn-right"></a>
            <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="b" id="coi_navbar2">
                          <ul>
                           <li><a href="#COI2">COI</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#COP2">COP</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#COQ2">COQ</a></li>
                         </ul>              
            </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="infoGuts2">
            ID:2<br />
           Data: asd <br />
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer-docs" data-theme="b" id="coi_footer2">
     <p>footer</p>  
    </div>
</div>

Doing this for each ID

</body>
```

The following are problems I am experiencing and after a while of goggling around cant find solutions to:

The Divs that are created loose there formatting(they lack the css)

The new divs seem to be mashed together (almost like I am creating the incorrectly) like the divs are not going into the correct spots like I have layed out in the body example.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try adding some content to your <div>s. A div with no content or with only white spaces renders differently.

Comment: Is your dynamic DOM structure what you expect it to be? If not, what does it look like?

Comment: I Updated the code with the corrections for the divs so they contain data.  

Note: I already had this in my code

Comment: Have you tried calling `('#coi1').trigger('create')`?

Comment: Would I use that for each of the new div elements that I create?

Comment: Ive tried both ways to no avail :(

Comment: Its kind of working now, I am still loosing the style for the div with the data-role="navbar", aksi the infoGuts is not populating with any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile documentation is really bad regarding this case. If I understood you correctly you want to refresh a css on a fully dynamically generated page. jQM documentation states to use this syntax **.trigger('create')** but unfortunately it is not working in jQM.

In your case you should use this syntax:

```
$("#index").trigger("pagecreate");
```

And here's an example for this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/mpFJn/

Comment: How would this work with completely 100% dynamic divs ? your example puts the new items inside of another div. How would you attach this block you added to the body of the page? Also I'm loosing the CSS in the navbar and I dont know why, Ive tried the pagecreate and refresh triggers but they didnt seem to work.

Comment: This would work just fine in any dynamic container (div etc...) as long it is appended to page header, content or footer before .trigger("pagecreate"). Also I don't have a problem with a navbar from your example so you probably have an error further in your code, sry can't help you with that without source example.